# Does convergence to normal distribution (central limit theorem) imply convergence in probability and expectation?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables, and let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences of real numbers. Assume that we have
$$
\frac{X_n-a_n}{b_n} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
in distribution, where $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ denotes the standard normal distribution.

My question is does our assumptions imply that $X_n/a_n \to 1$ in probability and $\mathbb{E}[X_n]/a_n\to 1$? What about $\mathbb{E}{X_n^2}$?

---

Further questions:
If the answer to the questions are all negative, is there any general sufficient condition on $a_n$ and $b_n$ that CLT implies convergence in probability or expectation?

I ask this question because convergence in probability or expectation is often easier to prove than convergence in distribution, so I wander when the latter actually implies the former.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example for first part: $X_n=-X$ for all $n$ where $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $a_n=0, b_n=1$.  [$X_n$ does not tend to $0$ in probability and $EX_n^{2}$ does not tend to $0$].

CLT theorem gives easy examples where the hypothesis is satisfied but $X_n$ does not even have finite mean.